# HttpHandler being overlooked in favor of route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httphandler, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have built a custom HttpHandler that issues a status page whenever a specific resource is requested by the load balancer.

Some more background: It can't be a controller as I need to be able to share it with other assemblies and the company coding policy is not to allow controllers from other assemblies.
Also, I cannot use a delegating handler as I don't want to affect the pipeline by adding a global message handler.

So I have the following in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
...
    <httpHandlers>
        <!-- Status Page-->
        <add verb="GET" path="*" type="Web.Api.Framework.StatusPageHandler, Web.Api.Framework" />
    </httpHandlers>
...
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
...
    <handlers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="StatusPageHandler" path="*" verb="GET" type="Web.Api.Framework.StatusPageHandler, Web.Api.Framework" />
    </handlers>
...
</system.webServer>
```

When I try to access the handler (http://foo.bar/status) it fails with a 404.  If I remove the resource mapping for the default controller (from global.asax) then it works. i.e. without the following statement in global.asax it works:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}", null, null);
```

I stumbled upon a url for which it does work: http://foo.bar/status/XXX, but that is hardly ideal - we don't want to have to extend the url in that "ugly" way.

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Can you explain "I cannot use a delegating handler as I don't want to affect the pipeline by adding a global message handler"?  By adding a HttpHandler your are affecting the pipeline, just in a different place.

Comment: Fair enough. My understanding was not right. I thought the web config definition would be the most effective way to achieve this, and that the framework would decide to use my handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get it to work. Change Web.Config like so.

```
<add name="StatusPageHandler" path="status" verb="GET" 
     type="Web.Api.Framework.StatusPageHandler, Web.Api.Framework" />
```

Add the line in Global.asax (RouteConfig.cs?) to ignore this route. Make sure you add this line before `routes.MapRoute`.

`routes.IgnoreRoute("status");`

Comment: Adding the routes.IgnoreRoute("status"); line was enough for this to work for http://foo.bar/status.
I have a flag to indicate whether diagnostic information should be shown - http://foo.bar/status/diag.  This was not working even after I added the ignore but it works when I add routes.IgnoreRoute("status/diag");
Thanks for your help @Badri

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  In WebApi2 the ignore route requires two arguments (name and path) so it would be `routes.IgnoreRoute("myroutename", "status");`  Also note that the webconfig line goes in `system.webServer/handlers`